# When running a public Jupyter server, what IP do you use?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

After you run jupyter notebook on a public server, it will output the following code as far as URL's go:
    https://[all ip addresses on your system]:8894/

So, my question is: What URL do I enter into *insert web browser* here in order to get it running?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find the IP address/(domain name if your machine has one) of your specific computer. If you're running Unix you can run `ifconfig` to get the IP address, if you're running Windows you can run `ipconfig` instead.